# Server-side copy/move of a Perforce folder - without local sync of files

Tags: version-control, perforce, depot

On the project I'm currently working on, we have lots of folders in the /branches and /tags folders (left after the migration from Subversion to Perforce).

I want to clean up the mess - I want to move/copy/rename folders remotely, directly on the depot, without getting them locally. I can't get them locally because we're talking about hundreds of GB and probably millions of files - dozens of branches x ~5GB.

**Is it possible to order Perforce to move the folders just on the server?**

(I do not have direct access to the Perforce machine, I cannot move folders around on the server or update the Perforce database).

Comment: For a depot that size, you might want to email [Perforce Support](http://www.perforce.com/technical_support/contact_support). If you haven't used them, Perforce's support is kinda legendary. Way better than the tech support you're probably used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* that you can construct a workspace that maps all the files in question.  You can run `sync -k` to make Perforce think you have the files locally.  Then you can run `move -k` to move the files on the server.

Just FYI, `p4 copy` creates a new branch, whereas `p4 move` moves an existing branch to a new location.

Answer (score 8):

`p4 copy -v` allows you to copy files in the depot without syncing those files to your workspace. (See the [`copy` reference](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/copy.html) for more details.)

`p4 delete -v` allows you to delete files in the depot that are not synced to your workspace. (See the [`delete` reference](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/delete.html) or [KB Article #1148](http://kb.perforce.com/article/1148/deleting-a-file-without-syncing) for more details.)

Also `p4 move -k` allows you to move files in the depot without moving them locally, but I'm not sure if that applies if you don't have them synced to your workspace. (See the [`move` reference](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/move.html) for more details.)

You can also accomplish a move with a `copy` followed by a `delete`.

Comment: Great. I missed the options when checking the command line options - presumably because my brain is hardwired by now to except -v to be "verbose" or "version" :)

I'll test today.

Comment: p4 move -k doesn't actually work for what I need :(


p4 delete -v says: Path '' is not under client '//myworkspace'. So no luck here either.
p4 copy -v does what is says, mostly, and it creates a changelist that you have to submit.

Still, the operations feel to heavy for what they're supposed to do (in most SCMs these kinds of operations just change a pointer/link/similar).